# Select an array based on another array in Python

Tags: python

I created these two arrays

```
students = np.array([['Hannah'],['Alonzo'], ['Antoinette'], ['Latasha'], ['Phil']])
grades = np.array([[86, 94], [83, 79], [97, 95], [90, 87], [73, 76]])
```

how do I select all rows from grade based on the student name, for example Alonzo?

I tried to select it all using index but for some reason the syntax was wrong, and I'm not sure how to select it.

Comment: Is `grades` actually a tuple of lists, as you've shown it?

Comment: Your `grades` should rather look like `grades = [[86, 94], [83, 79], [97, 95], [90, 87], [73, 76]]`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the wrong data structure - look into using a `dictionary` instead (the same concept is often called a `map` in other languages.)

If you want to push forward with what you have, look for an `indexOf` operation going by name, and then use that to access something from grades.

Though, that syntax looks strange to me - I think you're creating a tuple? In general it's difficult to dynamically index into a tuple - I assume there's a way to do it in python, but that's really not what they're for.

Comment: I'm not the most familiar with python syntax, but instead of making a tuple and converting it to an array (which is what I think you're doing), just declare it as an array in the first place.

Comment: Sure. I still recommend using a `dictionary` instead - it's a data structure that's really intended for this sort of "lookup value by key" operation. It saves you from having to manually implement the logic to do so, and has a lot of other supporting functions and advantages.

Comment: Well It's part of my class exercises and that's how it is in the exercise sheet we got!

Comment: Okay, if it's not something you can change than that's fine, but if you ever find yourself implementing something like this in an open-ended way... use a dictionary. (I'm sure there's an operation to zip two arrays or other list-like structures together so that they form the keys and values of a dictionary. That would be my approach here as well, but it's certainly not necessary if you already have something that works for you.)

Answer (score 0):

find the index from first array and then extract that index from grades:

```
find = 'Alonzo'

for i,student in enumerate(students):
    if student == find:
        print(grades[i])
        break
```

output:

```
>>
[83, 79]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
students = np.array([['Hannah'],['Alonzo'], ['Antoinette'], ['Latasha'], ['Phil']])
grades = np.array([[86, 94], [83, 79], [97, 95], [90, 87], [73, 76]])
grades[(students == ['Alonzo']).flatten()]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
students = np.array([['Hannah'],['Alonzo'], ['Antoinette'], ['Latasha'], ['Phil']])

grades = np.array([[86, 94], [83, 79], [97, 95], [90, 87], [73, 76]])

for index,student in enumerate(students):
    if student == 'Alonzo':
        print(grades[index])
```

output:

```py
[83 79]
```